# react navigation deep linking exclude few url path

Tags: react-native, android-intent, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-navigation-v6

Im using: `react navigation v6` `react native 0.63.3`

I do config deep linking in my project, But I need exclude a path in my url

In my link has some paths and I need 2 path for deep linking `/m` and `/tag`

But my link has another path with name `/app` and I don't want this path, I mean when i touched `www.example.com/app` deep linking and android intent ignore it.

```
const deepLinking = {
    prefixes: [
      'https://www.example.com',
      'http://www.example.com',
      'https://*.example.com',
      'http://example.com',
      'https://example.com',
      'example://'
    ],
    config: {
      screens: {
        HOME: 'home',
        LIVE: 'm/:uuid',
        TAGList: 'tag/:enVal',
      }
    }
  }
```

AndroidManifest :

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="example" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible :(

But you could possibly handle those by rendering a webview, like described here in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#handling-unmatched-routes-or-404

Essentially, something like this (copied from docs):

```js
    config: {
      screens: {
        HOME: 'home',
        LIVE: 'm/:uuid',
        TAGList: 'tag/:enVal',
        NotFound: '*',
      }
    }
```

```js
function NotFoundScreen({ route }) {
  if (route.path) {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: `https://mywebsite.com/${route.path}` }} />;
  }

  return <Text>This screen doesn't exist!</Text>
}
```